# import functions from modules in the same directory

Tags: python

I have two modules:

```
test1.py
   def func

test2.py
```

these two files (modules) are in the same directory. in test2.py, I want to import 'test1':

```
from test1 import func
```

It reports "func" as unresolved symbol. Why is it that? because they are in the same directory.

test1.py

```
def func():
    print("test1")
```

test2.py

```
from test1 import func
```

They are super simple. But don't understand why it complains "unresolved import"

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Normally, this should work, although if test1.py really looks like the line you have above, you'd get a syntaxerror.

Comment: Python 3. No syntax error. I omitted.

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess you have a circular import problem, in other words module `test1` imports module `test2` and vice versa (eiher directly or indirectly, i.e. for example `test2` imports a module `test3` that imports `test1`).

When this happens the one of the two will see the other as a partially loaded module ad import time with some of the functions/classes/variables undefined.

Comment: Maybe it is because ''test1.py" is not in the search path?